# Multiple lifetimes and move: assignment to borrowed `x` occurs here

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime, borrowing

I have a struct with a function `next()` (similar to iterators but not an iterator). This method returns the next state after modification (preserving the original state). So: `fn next(&A) -> A`.

I started with a simple struct where I didn't need a lifetime (struct A in the example) and I extended it to add a reference to a new struct (struct B).

The problem is that I now need to specify the lifetime for my struct and for some reason my method `next()` refuses to work anymore.

I suspect that the lifetime of the new struct of every iteration is limited to the scope where it is created and I cannot move it outside of this scope.

Is it possible to preserve the behavior of my `next()` method?

[Try it here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3be70d622d936939f2f48e5d4556b3c4&version=stable&mode=debug)

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct A(u32);
#[derive(Clone)]
struct B<'a>(u32, &'a u32);

impl A {
    fn next(&self) -> A {
        let mut new = self.clone();
        new.0 = new.0 + 1;
        new
    }
}

impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn next(&self) -> B {
        let mut new = self.clone();
        new.0 = new.0 + 1;
        new
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A(0);
    for _ in 0..5 {
        a = a.next();
    }

    let x = 0;
    let mut b = B(0, &x);
    for _ in 0..5 {
        b = b.next();
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `b` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:31:9
   |
31 |         b = b.next();
   |         ^^^^-^^^^^^^
   |         |   |
   |         |   borrow of `b` occurs here
   |         assignment to borrowed `b` occurs here
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn next(&self) -> B {
        let mut new = self.clone();
        new.0 = new.0 + 1;
        new
    }
}
```

You didn't specify a lifetime for `B`, the return type of `next`. Because of Rust's [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html), the compiler infers that you intended this:

```
impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn next<'c>(&'c self) -> B<'c> {
        let mut new = self.clone();
        new.0 = new.0 + 1;
        new
    }
}
```

Which means that the return value may not outlive `self`. Or, put another way, `self` has to live longer than the `B` that is returned. Given the body of the function, this is a *completely unnecessary requirement* because those references are independent of each other. And it causes a problem here:

```
for _ in 0..5 {
    b = b.next();
}
```

You are overwriting a value that the borrow-checker thinks is still borrowed by the call to `next()`. Inside `next` we know that there is no such relationship – the lifetime annotations do not reflect the constraints of what you're actually doing.

So what are the lifetime bounds here?

1. The lifetimes of references to `B` are unrelated - each can exist without the other. So, to give the most flexibility to a caller, the lifetime of `B` should be different from the lifetime of the reference to `self` in `next`.
2. However, each `B` that is created with `next()` holds a reference to *the same* `u32` as is held by `self`. So the lifetime *parameter* that you give to each `B` must be the same.

Using explicitly named lifetimes, this is the result of combining both of those things:

```
impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn next<'c>(&'c self) -> B<'a> {
        let mut new = self.clone();
        new.0 = new.0 + 1;
        new
    }
}
```

Note that — even though the *reference* to `self` here has lifetime `'c` — the type of `self` is `B<'a>`, where `'a` is the lifetime of the `&u32` inside. Just the same as the return value.

But actually, the `'c` can be elided. So it's really just the same as this:

```
impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn next(&self) -> B<'a> {
        let mut new = self.clone();
        new.0 = new.0 + 1;
        new
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not only a good answer, it helps me understand better those lifetimes. Thanks a 100x times!